# mensaje de espera en JAVA EE

Tags: java, servlets

Estoy desarrollando mi primera aplicación web con Java y tengo una pequeña duda.
Tengo mi archivo jsp dónde tengo mi pagina principal, mi css y un servlet con el que realizo las operaciones que necesito.
Bien, este servlet genera un archivo que luego devuelve al usuario para descargar y me gustaría que se mostrase un mensaje de espera mientras éste se genera. Algo tipo gif que se ponga a dar vueltas mientras tanto, ya que la opción de crear una barra de progreso la veo más complicada.
Gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una forma de agregar un elemento de carga sencilla de la página es una imagen gif. podrías utilizar jQuery para mostrar el gif y cuando el contenido está listo ocultarlo.

En tu ccs agregar lo siguiente que es la url del gif que vas utilizar:

```
.loadinggif {
    background:url('http://www.hsi.com.hk/HSI-Net/pages/images/en/share/ajax-loader.gif') no-repeat right center;
}
```

Y en jsp:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id='inputsource' />
<br>
<button onclick="$('#inputsource').addClass('loadinggif');">Show Loading</button>
<br>
<button onclick="$('#inputsource').removeClass('loadinggif');">Hide Loading</button>
```

Ejemplo [Aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/msjaiswal/FAVN5/)

Comment: Funciona perfectamente, pero ahora me encuentro con otro problema. Te pongo en situación. Cuando le doy al boton para queme genere el fichero, el servlet lo empieza a generar, y lo que hace es redireccionar a la dirección donde se ha creado ese fichero para que lo descargue directamente. Es decir, el usuario no sale del index, por lo que la barra de carga una vez que se genera el fichero y se descarga, no se para. ¿cual sería la solución para ello? Muchísimas gracias